# Can we declare function prototypes in DXL?

Tags: function-prototypes, ibm-doors

Being new to the DXL programming language, I feel the urge to create a set of basic functions and arrange them to a library (a folder with *.inc files). Such a library would be structured by content and would consist of several files defining functions for various aspects, e.g. strings, arrays, modules etc.

Sometimes function `a()` from file A would use function `b()` from file B, while `b()` might use function `c()` from A. This appears to be a problem since DXL is parsed, not compiled and the parser is apparently not too bright.

Did I miss the section which explains how to declare function prototypes? Is there any other construct to declare functions before they are defined?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a way to define prototypes in DXL however you can make include files and create a library of functions. You just have to be aware of the order in which you include the files. If you try to group them into similar functional areas you should be ok (general, Items, Modules, Objects, etc).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can prototype functions the same way you would in C or C++.

```
void c();
```

You can put prototypes into a separate file if desired, so long as #includes do not become circular.